# How come when I run my code I don't get information about the web page I'm scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm just getting started in web scraping and am following a tutorial, and when I run the code below as per the video I should be seeing the header of the web page, however when I run it in vstudio no information about the website pops up whereas when he runs his code, which looks like its in a shell of some sort, displays the title of the page. Forgive me I'm a noob

```
import bs4
#uReq is our arbitrary shorthand for urllib.request
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#The URL we plan to use
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/'

#uReq(my_url) opens up web client
Client = uReq(my_url)
#uClient.read dumps everything out of the url
html_page = Client.read()
Client.close()

#Putting our html page into beautifulsoup from bs4
#html parser
page_soup = soup(html_page, "html.parser")
page_soup.h1
```

Comment: Try putting `page_soup.h1` into a print statement

Comment: When I do that it just says "none".

Comment: does the page have `h1`?, try printing `print(page_soup)`

Comment: Ah thanks Om3r, I had assumed that it needed to have an H1 like what else would it start with lol, but when I printed H2 I got the expected result. Why would it not start with h1? or h0?

Comment: to answer that question then you will need to look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp